# Simulation in an Activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, simulation, physics

I have to design an android activity to host a physical simulation that evolves a system of bodies. The activity is composed of a SurfaceView that display the positions of bodies and some other Views (buttons) that control parameters such as time-speed and allow some interactions with the user.

To run the simulation I think is good to create a new thread class within the activity in order to have visibility on all activity's views. Anyway, it is a better practice to do calculations within this new thread and drawings and graphical updates on all Views in the UI thread.

I read that I can use the AsyncTask to perform this kind of things but it seem that AsyncTask is designed to perform something that has an end (think at the onPostExecute). My Task will not end until activity is destroyed because simulation will going on indefinitely.

Is this a problem with AsyncTask and I have to consider some other methods?

Answer (score 0):

You could perform calculations within the AsyncTask and update the GUI main thread periodically. A never-ending thread is no problem then.

But physics simulation is a topic on its own. So why not taking an existing physics simulation engine? There is box2d which has an [android port](https://code.google.com/p/androidbox2d/).